# How to create dynamic wordpress menu?

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, menu, custom-post-type

How can i create a dynamic menu in wordpress? I made a custom post type. I want to show the title of that custom post in the menu dropdown list.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can help with any specific issues, but this isn't a code writing service. There are tutorials available online.

Comment: <?php

                            $args = array('post_type' => 'post-form', 'showposts' => 5, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'date');
                            $city = new WP_Query($args);
                            while ($city->have_posts()):$city->the_post();
                                ?>
                              <?php  echo types_render_field("city", array("output"=>"html"));?>

Comment: so far i have written this code.. which dynamically adds title to navigation bar... how can i remove any duplicate titles??? For eg: there are two posts with title "New York City" but with different contents.. but i want to show only one "New York City" but when users click on "New York City" , it shows content of both posts. Thank you in advance